# jQuery - elegant way to trim() all elements in a doc?

Tags: jquery, trim

More joy cleaning up auto-generated html. Plenty of extraneous spaces injected into tags:

`<span>Lorem Ipsum&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> dolor sit...` (&nbsp; represents actual spaces, not the entity)

jQuery provides a $.trim() to truncate whitespace off the ends of a string. Is there a fast and elegant way I can apply this to an each() loop to remove all whitespace from all inline tags, or am I doomed to select => get html => trim => replace html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will remove the white space around any node that *has no element children*.

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length === 0;
}).text(function(_, old) {
    return $.trim(old);
});
```

The test for element children ensures that you don't incorrectly modify any elements with nested tags, although it may leave you with more spaces hanging around than you would like.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/c7aT6/

Comment: this won't cleanup nodes like `<span>  a <b>moose</b></span>` though

Comment: indeed it won't, but I don't think there is any perfect solution for that sort of scenario.

Comment: Even if it only takes out half of all instances, it saves me hours of going through and doing the rest by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$(selector).html(function(i, old){
    return $.trim(old);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bevacqua/bmfRE/)

Comment: serialising and then deserialising your entire DOM is never the right answer.  It has the potential to destroy any event handlers or other data on those elements.

Comment: he just asked for a more elegant way to do it, I'm not endorsing it

Comment: submitting that as an answer _is_ an implicit endorsement.

Comment: I merely assumed that if he wants to clean up auto-generated HTML it doesn't have any javascript handlers attached to it yet. I don't like the idea of going over every single node of a large DOM tree in client-side javascript either.